# Change datepicker format on submit (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a form with two datepickers. I am using JS to initiate the datepicker and then JS to build a url on submit using the values.

I want my date format to display to the user as mm/dd/yy, but I need the date to be added into the url as yy-m-d

Here is my form and the JS that process the form:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
// Booking Mask Submission
jQuery(function() {
 var form = jQuery('form#form1');
 form.submit(function(e) {
  var checkin = form.find('input[name="date_from"]').val();
  var nights = form.find('input[name="date_to"]').val();
  var guests = form.find('select[name="person"]').val();
  
  var bookingLink = "https://example.com" + checkin + "&depart=" + nights + "&adult=" + guests + "&?";
  form.attr('action',bookingLink);
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form class="book-form"  method="post" id="form1" > 
<div class="container">  
<span class="title">book a room</span>  
<div class="area">   
<div class="col date-holder">    
<div class="date"> <input type="text" name="date_from" class="from" placeholder="ARRIVAL">    </div>  
   
<div class="date"> <input type="text" name="date_to" placeholder="DEPARTRUE" class="to" >    </div> 
  </div>   
<div class="col">    <select class="person" name="person" placeholder="GUESTS">     <option>1</option>     <option>2</option>     <option>3</option>     <option>4</option>     <option>5</option>    </select>   </div>
<div class="col"> <input type="submit" value="get rates" class="btn">   </div>  </div>  </div></form>
```

Here is my datepicker js:

```js
// datepicker
function initDatepicker() {
 jQuery('.date-holder').each(function() {
  var holder = jQuery(this);
  var from = holder.find('input.from');
  var to = holder.find('input.to');
  from.datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
   hiddenName: true,
   onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    to.datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
   }
  });
  to.datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
   onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    from.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
   }
  });
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In addition, I also have code that makes the second date picker calendar auto set to the day after the first date.

To recap, I want the input field to display mm/dd/yy but convert to yy-m-d for the submission

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to manually format the date for you. For example in your submit function:

```
checkin = formatDate(checkin);

function formatDate(myDate) {
    var date = new Date(myDate);
    var yearFormatted = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
    var monthFormatted = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var dayFormatted = date.getDate();

    var dateFormatted = yearFormatted + '-' + monthFormatted + '-' + dayFormatted;

    return dateFormatted;
}
```

Comment: If I add that, it breaks the datepicker calendar and the calendar does not pop up when you click the box

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure I understand. Why would it do that? The only value utilizing the dates would be `bookingLink` right? How does that interact with your calendar? You could leave your variables as they were before and just do `var bookingLink = "https://example.com" + formatDate(checkin) + "&depart=" + formatDate(nights) + "&adult=" + formatDate(guests) + "&?";`

Comment: I added it in the wrong place. I got the calendar to work, but it converts the date to this "aN-NaN-NaN" in the url

Comment: I can't reproduce that error:
[https://jsfiddle.net/q55nu30o/](https://jsfiddle.net/q55nu30o/)